# What are the names of sahabas who were ashra-mubashra

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, jannah, islamic-basis

I want to know the complete names of sahabas who were known as ashra-mubashra. Anyone who knows about it can tell here. Thank you

Comment: There are posts answering this already on the site use the search function and you'll find them.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> Narrated 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> "Abu Bakr is in Paradise, 'Umar is in Paradise,
> 'Uthman is in Paradise, 'Ali is in Paradise, Talha is in Paradise,
> Az-Zubair is in Paradise, 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf is in Paradise, Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas
> is in Paradise, Sa'eed is in Paradise, and Abu 'Ubaidah bin Al-Jarrah
> is in Paradise."

[Jami` at-Tirmidhi  Vol. 1, Book 46, Hadith 3747](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/49/144)